# How to listen for event on other element

Tags: javascript

(I asked similiar question yesterday but it went in another direction so posting again with more details)

I have a class/object that takes an ID of a html element, and then sets event handlers on said element.

```
like: batman.on("click",run_this_code());
```

The result of that is obviously to run the func/code when the elements click event is fired.

Now, my question is: How can I listen/watch for OTHER elements events?
say batman is a <button id="batman"> and superman is a textfield <input type="text" id="superman">
And I have an instance of my class as described above, for the button "batman".
How would I in that instance, listen for events on "superman".
pseudo code:

```
batman.listen("click","fired on element with ID superman",run_this_code());
```

The only thing I have come up with, which I dont know 100% how to do is to register all clicks on the document, with:

```
var arr;
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (!event.target.hasAttribute('track_me')) return;
    // code here that saves the click, and the ID, into an array (arr)
}, false);
```

and now other instances can somehow check for changes on the array (arr), and react accordingly.

Ok enough rambling, basically how can i do:

```
batman.listen("click","on_superman",function(){
    alert("this instance represents the 'batman' element, but the element 'superman' was just clicked.");
}
);
```

I do NOT want to write the code in the "superman" instance. That is just an example, I want to to be a universal function for my class, to listen for events on other instances.

Comment: *"The result of that is obviously to run the func/code when the elements click event is fired."* Not with the code you've shown it won't. It will immediately run `run_this_code` and then use its return value when calling `on` to set up the handler.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I ask because those `.on` calls look like jQuery, but you haven't tagged [tag:jquery].

Comment: the above is more pseudo code, the actual class i got is lots more to it and works as i described. but you are correct :) And no,  am not using jquerybut yes its inspired from that.

Answer (score 2):

> say `batman` is a `<button id="batman">` and `superman` is a textfield `<input type="text" id="superman">` And I have an instance of my class as described above, for the button "batman". How would I in that instance, listen for events on "superman"

You can get a reference to the `superman` element like this:

```
document.getElementById("superman")
```

or if you're using jQuery, as you seem to be, you can get a jQuery object containing that element like this:

```
$("#superman")
```

Then use `addEventListener` (on the element) or `on` (on the jQuery object) to listen for the `click` event.

```
document.getElementById("superman").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // superman clicked
});
```

or

```
$("#superman").on("click", function() {
    // superman clicked
});
```

The code doing that can be in any class or object method you want.

---

In a comment you've said:

> my goal is to have a function to react to any other elements events

You may be looking for event delegation: Most events *bubble*, and so you can put an event listener on some container (`document` itself if you want) and watch for the events to happen. The element that triggered the event is available as the `target` property of the event object your handler receives:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Use `e.target` here...
});
```

Example:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id + " click");
});
document.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id + " input: " + e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="one" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="two" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: im not using jquery. the solution would probably involve some kind of mutation observer or proxy. i idont want to hardcode in any IDs, my goal is to have a function to react to any other elements events.

Comment: @Jason - You're probably lookng for event delegation, I've added to the end of the answer.

Comment: yeah, but i think i have to create my own event on the document, and listen for it on my object. cant get the dispatch of custom even to work though